# Forward arguments to wrapped base class member

Tags: c++, std-function

I want to write a `callback` - wrapper around `std::function` without `operator bool`, which will do nothing in `operator()` if wrapped `std::function` in *empty* state. Here is my idea

```cpp
template <class... Arguments>
struct callback : std::function<void(Arguments...)>
{
    using base_t = std::function<void(Arguments...)>;

    using base_t::base_t;

    template <class... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        if (!static_cast<bool>(static_cast<base_t>(*this)))
            return;
        base_t::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    operator bool() const = delete;
};
```

But using my type in the next code results in compilation error

```cpp
int main()
{
    callback<int> f;
    f({});
}
```

The error is:

```
<source>:22:6: error: no match for call to '(callback<int>) (<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   22 |     f({});
```

Using the next implementation compiles, but do not suits me

```cpp
template <class... Arguments>
struct callback : std::function<void(Arguments...)>
{
    using base_t = std::function<void(Arguments...)>;

    using base_t::operator();
    operator bool() const = delete;
};
```

Can someone please elaborate what is the difference between the two and is there a way to fix the error, but with my requirements?

Comment: `{}` does not have any type so `Args` cannot be deduced.

Comment: From now I look at it and does not even remember what was i intended to do in attach code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class... Arguments>
struct callback : std::function<void(Arguments...)>
{
    using base_t = std::function<void(Arguments...)>;

    void operator()(Arguments... args) const
    {
        if (!static_cast<bool>(*this))
            return;
        base_t::operator()(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    }
    
    operator bool() const = delete;
};
```

this version will support the `f({})` syntax, *but* value arguments may be `move`d one additional time.

If you want to avoid that, you can do this little trick:

```
template <class... Arguments>
struct callback : std::function<void(Arguments&&...)>
{
    using base_t = std::function<void(Arguments&&...)>;

    void operator()(Arguments... args) const
    {
        if (!static_cast<bool>(*this))
            return;
        base_t::operator()(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    }
    
    operator bool() const = delete;
};
```

which turns the intermediate `std::function` into a pass-through forwarder.

Note that your `static_cast<bool>(*this)` also won't work.

```
if (!static_cast<base_t const&>(*this))
```

may be what you want.

Myself, I might go a step further.

```
template<class T>
struct to_optional {
  using type=std::optional<T>;
};
template<class T>
using to_optional_t = typename to_optional<T>::type;

template<class T>
struct to_optional<std::optional<T>>:to_optional<T>{};

template<class Sig>
struct callback;

template <class R, class... Args>
struct callback<R(Args...)> : std::function<R(Args&&...)>
{
    using base_t = std::function<R(Args&&...)>;

    to_optional_t<R> operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        if (!static_cast<bool>(*this))
            return std::nullopt;
        return base_t::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    operator bool() const = delete;
};
template <class... Args>
struct callback<void(Args...)> : std::function<void(Args&&...)>
{
    using base_t = std::function<R(Args&&...)>;

    bool operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        if (!static_cast<bool>(*this))
            return false;
        base_t::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return true;
    }
    
    operator bool() const = delete;
};
```

which allows return values and testing if the call occurred.

You'll also want to inherit the ctor of `std::function`, possibly guarding against invoking some methods with `callback` objects themselves.  It gets tricky.

---

Note that this is less insane than you might think.  Arguments of type `Args...` can be constructed from arguments of type `Args&&...` so long as move-construction is possible.

So `callback<bob, stacy, alice>` will work; a final function which takes `(bob, stacy, alice)` can be stored in a `std::function<void(bob&&, stacy&&, alice&&)>`.

Comment: Has `std::forward` lost its intended meaning in these solutions?  `Args` were forwarding references in the question.

Comment: @DrewDormann `std::forward` is a conditional move, nothing more nothing less.  It does what I want it to do.  In addition, we *are* forwarding arguments, just not (always) universal references.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but given e.g. `callback<std::string> f;` if I called `f(some_string_lvalue);` then `std::forward<Arguments>(args)...` would be `std::forward<std::string>(args)` which would incorrectly cast that lvalue to an rvalue.  No?

Comment: @DrewDormann `callback::operator()` takes `std::string` by-value.  So we forward out of that argument into the `std::function<void(std::string&&)>`.  If that `std::function` stores `[](std::string s)`, the argument to `std::function` is then forwarded into that.  OTOH, if you had a `std::function<void(std::string)>`, the argument would store a copy in the `std::function` arguments, and *then* forward that argument into the `[](std::string s)` lambda.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please elaborate what is the difference between the two

`{}` doesn't have any type. So in the first case `Args` cannot be deduced and hence we get the error.

In the *second case*, for `callback<int>`, `using base_t::operator()` will be the same as `using std::function<void (int)>::operator()`. And since `{}` is a valid argument for `int`, this works without any problem. This can be seen from [over.ics.list#9.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9.2):

> if the initializer list has no elements, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  void f(int);
>
>  f( { } );               // OK: identity conversion
> ```
>
> — end example ]